# BAVET Constraint streams seem to be non-reproducible

Tags: optaplanner

I have a working solution using Drools constraints streams with two kinds of tests:

1. Constraint tests (both individual, as well as a combined one using `ConstraintVerifier`)
2. *Integration-style test* which actually uses the solver to solve a set of *golden* problems (solutions are known and asserted on).

I'm using a step-based termination to have a fully reproducible setup (random seed=0, local-search=SA).
I can see that it's reproducible, because multiple runs of those tests produce the same results in the same number of steps.

In the interested of performance optimization (and subsequently solution optimization) I tried to switch constraint streams from Drools (default?!) to Bavet.
The result for my two kinds of tests is as follows:

1. Still green, significant speed increase of ~20x.
2. Some tests are failing because they no longer find the optimal solution (but they are way faster). What's especially interesting, is that the non-optimal solution that they find differs from one test run to the next.

Is there something inherit in the Bavet implementation that is non-reproducible, e.g. does it use its own `Random` instance or does it rely on `System.identityHashCode()` or something like that?
I'd very much like to have a faster score calculation, but I favor reproducibility over speed.

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention that in order to make my constraints work with Bavet I had to rewrite them using `groupBy` a lot (instead of `map` which was failing with `UnsupportedOperationException`).
Could it be a combination of that, i.e. `groupBy` + Bavet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot to unpack here. First of all, Bavet is experimental and not (yet) feature complete. That is why you are seeing those exceptions, and it should probably be the answer to the reproducibility question too. Drools is our default CS implementation, and there are good reasons for it.

With that out of the way, let's look deeper. The problem you are describing looks a lot like score corruption. Please see [environment mode documentation](https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/planner-configuration/planner-configuration.html#environmentMode) for how to figure out if that is the case. If the default implementation shows score corruptions, most likely your constraint provider needs more work. If the Bavet implementation shows score corruptions, it can either be a problem in your constraint provider, or in Bavet itself - after all, it is still experimental.

As a final point, I would not compare CS-D and CS-B so directly. If your constraint providers are not identical, you should not expect the two CS implementations to produce the same results, unless you have proven step by step that your constraint variants actually do result in the same constraint matches. If you intend to do that, [Constraint Verifier](https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/constraint-streams/constraint-streams.html#constraintStreamsTesting) will help you.

As a side note, if `map()` was where you saw the `UnsupportedOperationException`, that has only been implemented in 8.27.0.Final, out soon. Please upgrade.

Comment: @whiskeysierra I'd love to know how your original constraintProvider (the one that works with Drools) works with Bavet on OptaPlanner 8.27.0.Final, where it won't throw an UnsupportedOperationException. It should deliver the exact same steps/move/scores, or there's a bug. 8.27 is hopefully out by end of next week. No promises.

Comment: Yes, I'm using 8.26.0.Final right now and the problem was indeed map(). I'll give 8.27 a try, once it's out and let you know the results.

Comment: @whiskeysierra OptaPlanner main is stable this morning, so if you 're motivated, you can `git clone ...` it and `mvn clean install -DskipTests` it and try it out locally with `8.27.0-SNAPSHOT`. If you discover any issues with your use case, we can probably still fix it before 8.27.0.Final actually goes out. The build takes 5 minutes or so.

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet I just tried 8.27 (417edbf4f0) locally it doesn't work as a drop-in replacement for my original constraint providers (which are using map() a lot). CH never creates an initial solution, it just leaves all planning variables set to null (they are nullable, but it should penalize that).

Comment: @lukáš-petrovický I confirm your suspicion: My rewritten/refactored constraint providers were incorrect. They were also broken for CS-D. Once I corrected that, CS-D and CS-B produced identical results with a speed increase of ~16-20x.

That means after rewriting my constraint providers properly from using map to groupBy (which we needed for other reasons anyway) we're now using 8.26 + Bavet successfully.

Comment: I am glad it works for you. Still, proceed with caution - Bavet is not the default, and will not be for quite some time still. If you have a long-term positive experience, we'd like to know - and if it's negative, we'd like to know that even more, of course.

Comment: @whiskeysierra What is your speed difference (score calculation count in the INFO logging) between CS-D (Drools) and CS-B (Bavet)?

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet
Test suite (50 tests, using ConstraintVerifier)
CS-D ~12-15s
CS-B <500ms

Production
CS-D score calculation speed (5277/sec)
CS-B score calculation speed (18403/sec)

Comment: The ConstraintVerifier use case probably isn't too representative - CS-D will suffer there by having to compile the rule base, so the cold starts are very slow and with ConstraintVerifier, every start is a cold start. But the production numbers match what we see on our end.

Comment: Good to know. Test suite performance is still nice for developer productivity :D

Comment: Thank you for sharing those numbers! Bavet is 3.48 times faster. Nice.